# Error when installing and launching cevelop for first time on mac

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, c++14, cevelop

I am trying to install Cevelop on my mac (Sierra 10.12.6) and after downloading and installing Cevelop from the download site and trying to launch, I am getting the following error log. I have installed Java 8.

What am I doing wrong?

```
!SESSION Thu Jan 04 15:20:08 JST 2018 -------------------------------
!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.launcher 4 0 2018-01-04 15:20:08.563
!MESSAGE Exception launching the Eclipse Platform:
!STACK
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: 
org/eclipse/core/runtime/adaptor/EclipseStarter : Unsupported 
major.minor version 51.0
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:637)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:621)
    at 
java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:650)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:590)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1499)
```

Comment: You need to upgrade to a modern version of Java (at least Java 7)

Comment: Thanks. I just figured out that I needed to install JRE and JDK, and it worked.